# How Do I Pass A Dollar To Gradle In Azure DevOps?

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My build.gradle has username and password variables in it:

```
maven {
    url 'https://artifactory.example.com/'
    credentials {
        username "$artifactory_username"
        password "$artifactory_password"
    }
```

}

These are passed in via the command line like this:

```
./gradlew -Partifactory_username='myUser' -Partifactory_password='myPa$sw0rd'
```

Now that I am running in Azure DevOps I have a yml pipeline with the username and password as pipeline variables.

```
- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    options: '-Partifactory_username=${user} -Partifactory_password=${password}'
    tasks: 'jar'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
```

This works fine with a simple password but it fails when the password has the dollar sign in it.
Looking at the build log, I can see that Azure DevOps isn't passing in the whole password on the command line to Gradle.

I have tried various different quoting styles but I can't get it to pass the full password:

```
    options: '-Partifactory_username=${user} -Partifactory_password=${password}'
    options: "-Partifactory_username='${user}' -Partifactory_password='${password}'"
    options: '-Partifactory_username=$${user} -Partifactory_password=$${password}'
```

I can't change the password and I can't escape it in the Variables as both are controlled by other people.

It has something to do with the way it is creating it in bash because the same code works correctly on a Windows agent. The production agents are Linux so I have to get it working in bash.

Comment: Did you try the classical way? i.e. using backslashes for escaping. Try with 1 or if it does not work 2, or if it does not work 3 and so on until it eventually works. You could need to get through several layers of things for which you need to escape it. If it worked, I can make this comment an answer so that you can accept and up-vote it. :-)

Comment: What are you suggesting I escape? The dollar is in the password so I can't modify it in the Variable by putting an escape character in it

Comment: In the `options` value where you already tried various quotings